# Django: how to automatically also delete file from storage when Clear Checkbox ticked?

Tags: python, django, storage

I have a user profile model with optional avatar that looks like

```
#models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model): 
     avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatars null=True, blank=True)
     .
     .
     .
```

Then a form like:

```
#forms.py
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False,....)
    class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
```

Finally, a view including

```
#views.py
def edit_profile(....)
    profile_obj = request.user.userprofile
    form = UserProfile(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=profile_obj)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

Now when the template for editing the user's profile, and avatar, is rendered, it included a `Clear` checkbox, which when selected let's the user remove their avatar photo. It leaves `myuser.avatar` in the state `<ImageFieldFile: None>`, however it does not delete the file in the storage area of the site itself (i.e. the jpg,png or whatever). I've read that this is by design in `Django 1.6`, which is all well and good, but how do I override this feature, so that the file is indeed deleted to?

From the shell there exists no problem:

```
from myapp.models import UserProfile
user1==UserProfile.objects.all()[0]
user1.avatar.delete()
```

Removes the `jpeg` too.

---

**EDIT:**

I tried using a signal like:

```
#models.py
.
.
.
@receiver(post_delete, sender=UserProfile)
def avatar_post_delete_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'DEBUG: avatar delete triggered'
    avatar = kwargs['instance']
    storage, path = avatar.original_image.storage, avatar.original_image.path
    storage.delete(path)
```

but this did not even trigger, I guess because I'm not deleting the `UserProfile` object
in its entirety when the user selects the clear checkbox, but rather just the avatar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extend the ImageField like this and use it instead:

```
class ImageField(models.ImageField):

    def save_form_data(self, instance, data):
        if data is not None: 
            file = getattr(instance, self.attname)
            if file != data:
                file.delete(save=False)
        super(ImageField, self).save_form_data(instance, data)
```

This will delete the old file if you replace it with the new one, or mark it to clear.
[Here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L320) is the explanation why.

**Edit:**

There is also an app [django-smartfields](https://github.com/lehins/django-smartfields) that includes this functionality plus more, like automatic re-sizing, automatic conversion of images and videos, etc. It achieves it in a more complicated way though, using field descriptors and model customization. But it is very simple to use:

```
from smartfields import fields

class UserProfile(models.Model): 
    avatar = fields.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', blank=True)
```

It will also remove files whenever:

- field value was replaced with a new one (either uploaded or set manually)
- the model instance itself containing the field is deleted.

Comment: Thanks!  One question: what if the user attempts to upload a new file that is genuinely different but named the same way as the old one?

Comment: It will even replace the file if you upload exactly the same file you uploaded first, because 'data' will be either InMemoryUploadedFile or TemporaryUploadedFile, while 'file' will be ImageFieldFile. So if you really want to be sure you can check if their classes equal, but I've tested it plenty of times it works as expected.

Comment: Great solution. I grinded through this problem thanks to your insightful example. I know it's been ages since you posted this, but I'm wondering when `file` would ever equal `data`?

Comment: @Jarad To be honest, I don't remember why the check necessary. I do remember that `file != data` was necessary otherwise it was behaving incorrectly on some special cases of submitted forms. Possibly resubmitting and validation, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Oh, I see now. If a previous image existed and a "post" (or something) was saved without making changes to the image, the `file` with be equivalent to the `data` so in this case, don't delete the image. You're brilliant.

Comment: In my case, I modified the `if` statement a bit: `if bool(file) == True and file != data`. Maybe it'll help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution at all, but one hackish way might be to store the file for each user under just their username, then on catching a `pre_save` signal with an empty `instance.avatar.name` and where the user file exists on disk in the expected place, delete it. Yuck.

```
 class UserProfile(models.Model): 
      avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatars null=True, blank=True)
```

and

```
#save the avatar for each user as their username
def update_filename(instance, filename):
    path = "avatars"
    format = instance.user.username
    return os.path.join(path, format)
```

and

```
#if current instance has empty avatar.name
#and the file exists on disk where expected for user
#deduce user has clicked clear, delete file for user. 
@receiver(pre_save, sender=UserProfile)
def avatar_pre_save_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    avatar_filepath = settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/avatars/'+ instance.user.username
    if not instance.avatar.name and os.path.isfile(avatar_filepath):
        os.remove(avatar_filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more possible way (that doesn't require special naming of files) is overriding form save method, then calling it with the old avatar as kwarg:

```
#forms.py
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(UserProfileForm, self).save(commit=False)
        old_avatar_name = kwargs.pop('old_avatar_name', None)
        new_avatar_name = None
        if self.cleaned_data['avatar']:
            new_avatar_name = self.cleaned_data['avatar'].name
        if old_avatar_name != new_avatar_name:
            old_avatar_filepath = settings.MEDIA_ROOT +'/'+ old_avatar_name
                if os.path.isfile(old_avatar_filepath):
                    os.remove(old_avatar_filepath)

         if commit:
             instance.save()
         return instance
```

Then in the view:

```
def edit_profile(request,....):

    .
    .
    .
    try:
        profile_obj = request.user.userprofile
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profiles_create_profile'))

    if profile_obj.avatar.name:
        avatar_kwargs={'old_avatar_name': profile_obj.avatar.name}
    else:
        avatar_kwargs={}
    .
    .
    .
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(**avatar_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Mixin like below

```
class ImageDeleteMixin(object):

  def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.avatar:
        storage, path = self.avatar.storage, self.avatar.path
        super(ImageDeleteMixin, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
        storage.delete(path)
    else:
        super(ImageDeleteMixin, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     if self.id:
        old_instance = self.__class__._default_manager.get(pk=self.pk)
        if (
         old_instance.avatar != self.avatar and old_instance.avatar and
         old_instance.avatar.path
        ):
            storage, path = old_instance.avatar.storage, old_instance.avatar.path
            super(ImageDeleteMixin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            storage.delete(path)
            return
    return super(ImageDeleteMixin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class UserProfile(ImageDeleteMixin, models.Model): 
   avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatars null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your use case, you could hook into Django's Singals:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-delete

Or, in a view, when the "checked" variable is sent back to the server, delete the avatar!

Comment: I tried the signal method, I've now added to my OP, which I stumbled across in another post, but this does not even trigger. I'm not sure how else to implement a signal based approach?

Comment: Also using signals on save, makes it hard to know if Clear checkbox was ticked or not...

Comment: Maybe views is the way to go, but how do I access this `Clear` checkbox variable?